# What's the best way to routinely import DBase (dbf) files into MySQL tables?

Tags: python, mysql, dbf, dbase

The DBF files are updated every few hours. We need to import new records into MySQL and skip duplicates. I don't have any experience with DBF files but as far as I can tell a handful of the one's we're working with don't have unique IDs.

I plan to use Python if there are no ready-made utilities that do this.

Comment: If there are no ID - how to find duplicates?

Comment: Maybe consider all columns to determine uniqueness, or possibly use a row # in the DBF file. I'm not entirely sure, honestly.

Answer (score 0):

The DBF-format was developed more than 30 years ago, when the typical PC used to have 640K of RAM. It is very easy to read, back in the day I wrote an Autocad database driver for it (yes, I'm old). Basically all you have to do is to create a few C structs and load/dump them from/to disk.

There is a [Python library for reading DBF files](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dbf/), I use it from time to time because Shapefiles (a popular GIS data format) often contains a DBF file.

Example:

```
>>> from dbf import Table
>>> placenames = Table('PLCNAM.DBF', codepage='cp1252')
>>> placenames.open()
>>> for place in placenames:
...     print(place.count, place.name)
41   Springfield
26   Clinton
25   Madison
24   Franklin
...
```

May be you want to take a look at this project: http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbfconverter/

Answer (score -1):

When you say you are using dBase, I presume you have access to the (.) dot prompt.

At dot prompt convert the .dbf file into a delimited text file.

Reconvert the delimited text file into a MySql data file with the necessary command in 
MySql. I do not know the actual command for it.  All DBMS will have commands to do that
work.

For eliminiating the duplicates you will have to do it at the time of populating the 
data to the .dbf file through a programme written in dBase.